# Quota exceeded for quota metric 'speech.googleapis.com/default_requests' not really understandable

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I'm currently playing with a GCP service called API Speech-to-Text, using the NodeJS client library.
For that, I followed the quickstart documentation, trying to recognize a short local audio file (quite simply) first. However, I keep getting this error when I run `node test_sample.js` :

```sh
ERROR: { Error: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'speech.googleapis.com/default_requests' and limit 'DefaultRequestsPerMinutePerProject' of service 'speech.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:764086051850'.
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/Users/macOSuser/Projects/nodejs-speech/samples/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:102:45)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:198:15)
    at Http2CallStream.endCall (/Users/macOSuser/Projects/nodejs-speech/samples/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:74:18)
    at /Users/macOSuser/Projects/nodejs-speech/samples/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:163:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
```

**Note : the mentioned project_number is not the same as mine**

I have already tried to change my default gcloud project/account, as well as creating a brand new project and activating the API again.
I also checked on the GCP Console how were my request graphs, and yes they are empty

The sample code for quickstart can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries)

Thank you for your help on that

Edit solved : This was an authentification issue, which I solved using a service account's JSON key and refering by running `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/PATH-TO-FILE/key.json"`.
Thanks @JJ Geewax

Comment: You exceeded your quota. Check your code to see how many API requests you're making. A poorly structured loop could quickly cause this problem.

Comment: It's basically GCP's quickstart + my audio is 30s long + even 1 day later I don't see any recorded request on the GCP console's quotas graph. Don't think this is a code issue

Comment: Hi, I'm having exactly the same problem. Seems Google has just changed something in the authentication method.

Comment: Yes it's an authentification issue and I found this error message quite misleading ...

Comment: Solved: simply put, Google now want your credit card number; instead of blocking your request if you use the API more than 60 minutes in a month, they invoice you... so you have to create a service account, enable the API and agree to pay after 60 minutes per month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noted that the project number isn't the same as the one you're seeing the error result, so that seems to be the bigger problem here... The Google Cloud client libraries get the project information and credentials from a few different places (with different priorities for each), so it's possible that you're accidentally picking up credentials and identity from the application defaults (possible the `gcloud` command-line tool). Can you update the question with the code you're running to get this error?

There are a few ways to fix an issue like this, but the easiest is probably to just run: 
`gcloud auth application-default login` 
in the command line ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)).

Once you follow the authentication flow, you should end up with credentials for the intended project.

You also might want to take a look at the [Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account) guide for GCP in Node.js which talks about creating a service account and setting those credentials using an environment variable.

Comment: To precise your answer that allowed me to work around my issue : the command `gcloud auth application-default login` didn't change anything. You really have to set up a service account, get the JSON key, store it somewhere and setup `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="PATH-TO-FILE/key.json"`

Comment: @hyone did you have to create an invoicing account

Comment: I think you found the answer by yourself :)